# Can someone explain how this for loop works?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

This function returns the largest number from an array. I need help on understanding the if part: `if (arr[i] > maxNumber) {maxNumber = arr[i]}`. Using pseudocode or an explanation how exactly does this work?

```js
function max(arr){
    let maxNumber = 0
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > maxNumber){
            maxNumber = arr[i]
        }
    }
    return maxNumber
}

console.log(max([1,2,3,40,5]));
```

Comment: why not simply use `Math.max(...arr)`?

Comment: @Lawrence: Homework assignment.

Comment: Examine the code line by line. So you have a variable maxNumber with value of 0, and you are looping the arr, first `arr[i]` is value of 1 so it's bigger then maxNumber so you assign 1 to maxNumber variable. on the second loop, you have value of `2` from `arr[i]` and again you check if it's bigger then current maxNumber value which is 1 at the time.
So go on like this, you are returning back 40 cause it's the biggest in that array =)

Comment: Homework assignment indeed. Thanks Halil, wonderful explanation.

Comment: Hopefully the max number is aways greater than zero.

Comment: I'm very new to stack overflow obviously as this is my first ever post.  Why is it being downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function max(array) {
    largest number is equal to 0;
    for (i is equal to 0; i is less than the length of array; increment i by 1 each time) {
        if (the item at the current index is greater than the previous largest number) {
            set the largest number to to the item at the current index;
        }
    }
    return largest number which will be 0 if no larger number is found
}
```

Worth noting that if all values in the array are negative, it will return 0;
This will work for negative numbers too.

```js
function max(arr){
    let maxNumber = -Infinity
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > maxNumber){
            maxNumber = arr[i]
        }
    }
    return maxNumber
}
```

Comment: I like the last statement,  *largest number which will be 0 if no larger number is found*. 0 is not in the array, so would fail a unit test. the tripe they teach.

Answer (score 0):

What this part: `if (arr[i] > maxNumber) {maxNumber = arr[i]}` doing is checking if the current array member is greater than the current maxNumber and if it is changing the maxNumber value to the current array.

In short, `max(whatEverArray)` will always return zero or the biggest value of the array. and if it return zero, means all the array values are either zero or less than zero.